# Hang when using numpy_input_fn

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand how to use input functions and estimators.  When I try to use a numpy input function, tensorflow hangs.  Am I doing something wrong here?  I am running TensorFlow 1.6.0 with Python 3.6.4 on MacOS 10.13.

Here is an example of the code that hangs:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

infun = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": a},
      batch_size=2,
      num_epochs=3,
      shuffle=False)

batch = infun()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(batch))
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` method hangs because it requires queue runners to feed the inputs. The queue runners are usually handled by the `tf.estimator` methods, so to run it yourself in a session you'd have to setup and start the queues.

The newer `tf.data.Dataset` is an easier solution, since you can use it directly in a `tf.Session` and it is also compatible with the `tf.estimator` methods:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({"x": a})
dataset = dataset.repeat(3) # number of epochs
dataset = dataset.batch(2) # batch size

batch = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(batch))
```